# Search variable for multiple substrings

Tags: sh, bsd

Working on a BSD system and having difficultly searching a variable to see if it contains any of multiple different substrings. This is what I have that works:

```
> echo $lenck   if test "${lenck#*$pattern1}" != "$lenck";              
> then
>      if test "${lenck#*$pattern2}" != "$lenck";                                            
>      then
>      echo "Invalid or corrupted IP or process"
>      echo $lenck | tee -a invalid.txt
>      else
>          pat2out=$lenck
>          if test "${pat2out#*$pattern3}" != "$pat2out";
>          then
>          echo "Invalid or corrupted IP or process"
>          echo $pat2out | tee -a invalid.txt
>          else
>            pat3out=$pat2out
>            if test "${pat3out#*$pattern4}" != "$pat3out";
>            then
>            echo "Invalid or corrupted IP or process"
>            echo $pat3out | tee -a invalid.txt
>            else
>            echo $pat3out | tee -a processed.txt
>            fi
>          fi
>       fi
> 
>   else
>      echo "Invalid or corrupted IP or process"
>      echo $lenck | tee -a invalid.txt   fi
```

The problem is that I need to be able to search for many more than four patterns. Tried grep -e and other approaches but they aren't correctly filtering the strings to the correct file. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all of your tests actually test against the same input string, so you could use a [case statement](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05):

```
echo "$lenck"
case "$lenck" in
  *$pattern1*|*$pattern2*|*$pattern3*)
    echo "Invalid or corrupted IP or process"
    echo "$lenck" >> invalid.txt
    ;;
  *)
    echo "$lenck" >> processed.txt
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: This is sending all the strings to invalid.txt. My patterns are as follows: pattern1=".exe"
pattern2="\temp\"
pattern3="\users"  Would that make a difference?